# How to plot stacked sorted ribbon plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a stacked sorted ribbon plot like this shown below.

[image: Ribbon Plot]

```
data_orange <- data.frame("Y" = c(0.16,0.10,0.05,0,0.), 
                          "X" = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005))

data_light_blue <- data.frame("Y" = c(0.17,0.16,0.14,0.13,0.12), 
                              "X" = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005))

data_blue <- data.frame("Y" = c(0.00,0.01,0.04,0.08,0.12), 
                        "X" = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005))

data_red <- data.frame("Y" = c(0.36,0.32,0.26,0.19,0.09), 
                       "X" = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005))
```

I made this graph through excel but want to do in in r-studio.

Comment: Hi Kaung, can you post your data frame (or a subset of it) to make this reproducible, maybe with `dput`, and show us what your graph does look like as well?

Comment: @mysteRious i only have it in excel but want to replicate it for r studio. I have also put the data above each color has a unique dataframe.  the graph you show below does not look alike.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to use `geom_ribbon` that you may be able to manipulate to get the result you are looking for. It requires a little reformatting of the data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004), y=c(0.16,0.10,0.05,0,0,0.17,0.16,0.14,0.13,0.12,0,0.01,0.04,0.08,0.12,0.36,0.32,0.26,0.19,0.09), group=c("orange","orange","orange","orange","orange","lightblue","lightblue","lightblue","lightblue","lightblue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","red","red","red","red","red"))

> df2
      x    y     group
1  2000 0.16    orange
2  2001 0.10    orange
3  2002 0.05    orange
4  2003 0.00    orange
5  2004 0.00    orange
6  2000 0.17 lightblue
7  2001 0.16 lightblue
8  2002 0.14 lightblue
9  2003 0.13 lightblue
10 2004 0.12 lightblue
11 2000 0.00      blue
12 2001 0.01      blue
13 2002 0.04      blue
14 2003 0.08      blue
15 2004 0.12      blue
16 2000 0.36       red
17 2001 0.32       red
18 2002 0.26       red
19 2003 0.19       red
20 2004 0.09       red
```

Now you can plot like this. Change the constant (20) to change the width of the ribbon.

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group, colour=group)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=v-20*y, ymax=v+20*y, fill=group), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

*[After questioner added data, it became apparent that the solution below not appropriate chart for the data type, but leaving the answer here in case anyone is looking for the sankey plot.]*

Although there are prettier options (e.g. `networkD3`), the most straightforward way to make ribbon plots is with the `sankey` package. Here is the example from `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sankey/sankey.pdf`:

```
edges <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, textConnection(
" get_deps get_description
get_deps parse_deps
get_deps %||%
get_deps drop_internal
get_description pkg_from_filename
parse_deps str_trim
cran_file get_pkg_type
cran_file r_minor_version
download_urls split_pkg_names_versions
download_urls cran_file
pkg_download dir_exists
pkg_download download_urls
pkg_download filename_from_url
pkg_download try_download
restore pkg_download
restore drop_missing_deps
restore install_order
restore get_deps
split_pkg_names_versions data_frame
"))
```

The data structure looks like this:

```
> edges
                         V1                       V2
1                  get_deps          get_description
2                  get_deps               parse_deps
3                  get_deps                     %||%
4                  get_deps            drop_internal
5           get_description        pkg_from_filename
6                parse_deps                 str_trim
7                 cran_file             get_pkg_type
8                 cran_file          r_minor_version
9             download_urls split_pkg_names_versions
10            download_urls                cran_file
11             pkg_download               dir_exists
12             pkg_download            download_urls
13             pkg_download        filename_from_url
14             pkg_download             try_download
15                  restore             pkg_download
16                  restore        drop_missing_deps
17                  restore            install_order
18                  restore                 get_deps
19 split_pkg_names_versions               data_frame
```

This code produces the plot:

```
pkgsnap_sankey <- make_sankey(edges = edges)
sankey(pkgsnap_sankey)
```

[image]

Comment: I will try to manipulate  the parameter to see if it works thank you for the start!

Comment: in the first graph what is "v" in the ymin and ymax parameter?